# Release date of Renaissance's Ashes Are Burning?

Tags: album, prog-rock

The most precise release date I can find is *October 1973* (which means that unless I find more precise information, as far as I'm concerned today starts the month-long celebration of the 50th anniversary of this masterpiece! :‒) [*] )

Can someone tell, or better, point to a source that indicates the exact day in Oct 1973?

[*] Arguably a bit unfair to the likes of The Dark Side of the Moon, for which it was only in March 1 that I was actively celebrating its 50th anniversary! :‒)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashes_Are_Burning), it's **October 10th** of 1973, but it's unclear where this information comes from.

[This page on Genius](https://genius.com/Renaissance-ashes-are-burning-lyrics/q/release-date) gives the same information, but that could have been plucked from that Wikipedia page. I also found it on [this page](https://www.spirit-of-rock.com/en/album/Ashes_Are_Burning/33847), but, again, without a mention of the source.

(Nice album, by the way :)

Comment: Actually, if you see the page's history, you'll notice that *I* edited the page to include the release day (a while after I posted this question here). The source is the e-mail reply after I asked through the Contact form on the official Renaissance web site. They replied rather quickly, indicating that the release day was Oct 10, 1973 (I hope that they won't revert my edit on account of "Source needed", although I could see that happening).  I was going to remove this question, but after procrastinating a bit, I see that now there's your answer, so it seems unfair to remove it now.

Comment: And, oh, yes:  _really nice_ album indeed !!  (I was not kidding, I was prepared to celebrate its 50th anniversary the entire month of October!  :‒) )

Comment: @Cal-linux Haha, yeah, I saw no reason to check who edited the page, since that still doesn't elucidate where the information comes from. We're full circle, appropriate for the band name (and possibly the album title: I associate it with the phoenix) :)